# Following a link using Nokogiri for scraping

Tags: screen-scraping, nokogiri

Is there a method to follow a link using Nokogiri for scraping?  I know I can extract the href and open it, but I thought I saw a method to do this using hpricot and was wondering if there was something like that in Nokogiri.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an excellent [screen scraping guide](http://www.igvita.com/2007/02/04/ruby-screen-scraper-in-60-seconds/) for using Ruby, Nokigiri, Hpricot, and Firebug.

Personally I am a big fan of using [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/), which is a headless browser, for screen scraping.  You can use mechanize to navigate links and fill out forms and it will handle all the tricky stuff like cookies.